# CSS Style if not children

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to apply a style to an element if a specific class is NOT a child of the element.

```
<table class="printlist" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="list_wanted0"><td>Whatever...</td></tr>
    <tr class="list_wanted1"><td>
      <div class="journal">
        <table><tbody>
          <tr><td style="width: 9em">2011-03-12 09:36</td></tr>
        </tbody></table>
      </div>
    </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The example above is reduced to a minimum to demonstrate the structure.

What I want is to have the `:Hover` properties only to apply `.printlist tr` if `<tr>` has **NO** `.journal` child.

The `.list_wanted0` and `.list_wanted1` can not be used to select the `.journal`, it can be other class names there.

The CSS I have tried is:

```
.printlist tr:Hover * :not(itemjournal) {
  color: #000;
  background: #aaa
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work as I intended to.

If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask,
Thank you.

Comment: You cannot style an ancestor depending on its children with CSS; you can use JavaScript (or a library) to apply a class-name or add styles depending on such a condition, but not with *just* css.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### I got it to work

I thought I would answer my own question and present my pure CSS solution.

The solution was to create two classes and combine them in the `<tr>`

```
<table class="printlist" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="list_wanted0 list_hover"><td>Whatever...</td></tr>
    <tr class="list_wanted1"><td>
      <div class="journal">
        <table><tbody>
          <tr><td style="width: 9em">2011-03-12 09:36</td></tr>
        </tbody></table>
      </div>
    </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I only needed to add a hover class:

```
.list_hover:Hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #aaa
}
```

On all `<tr>` rows that needs hover I combine whatever class I like with the `.list_hover` class and exclude it from the `.journal` row.

Now it works exactly as intended. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: That is not pure CSS since you had to modify the HTML to get it to work.

Comment: So if I had added the hover class from the begining but didn't define the `:Hover` right, had it been pure CSS then? Same thing... :P

Comment: I wish you could downvote a comment. What value is CSS without markup? You can't do anything with 'pure css' if the corresponding markup is thrown out the window..

Comment: Totally agree with the first comment. This 'solution' does not answer the original question. It does not "apply a style to an element if a specific class is NOT a child of the element", instead it just applies a style to a class, and that class conveniently being added as necessary without explaining how. To be fair, the OP never said it had to be pure CSS, but in fact, BoltClock's first reply does exactly what the OP's own 'answer' does, through JS. Since BoltClock's reply also provides the reasons why, it is the preferred answer.

Answer (score 10):

It's impossible with CSS selectors alone; you can't use CSS to determine if an element has a certain kind of child or not. Your best bet is to use JavaScript to apply classes, and style those classes accordingly instead.

An example using the [jQuery-only `:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector):

```
$('.printlist tr').not(':has(.journal)').addClass('nojournal');
```

Then apply styles to `.printlist tr.nojournal:hover`.

Comment: :empty CSS selector been around for a long time

Comment: @Eugene Xa: Of course - my answer was poorly phrased so I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately you'll need to go with a javascript-based solution such as jQuery suggested by BoltClock, especially if you want the CSS styling to be consistent across browsers, considering the fact that not all browsers implement the complete CSS standard specifications.

If you still want to go ahead with CSS-only, try looking for a cheat-sheet table of what types of CSS selectors are supported in what browsers/versions.